# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" e "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

Pessoal estou tentando fazer uma integração MailChimp, mas estou tendo problemas com esse erro:

1 - Access-Control-Allow-Origin
2 - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Não consigo encontrar o problema. Conseguem me ajudar?

Para o erro  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

```js
formData = {
            u: "d6bd0bfa42c51cbaec3eb879b",
            id: "e943abd300"
        };

        $.ajax({
            url:"http://academiadopsicologo.us12.list-manage.com/subscribe/post",
            type:'GET',
            crossDomain:true,
            data:formData,
            dataType:'json',
            contentType:'application/json',

            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },

            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }

        });
```

Para o Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

```js
formData = {
    u: "d6bd0bfa42c51cbaec3eb879b",
    id: "e943abd300"
};

$.ajax({
    url:"http://academiadopsicologo.us12.list-manage.com/subscribe/post",
    type:'GET',
    crossDomain:true,
    data:formData,
    dataType:'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    contentType:'application/json',

    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },

    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }

});
```

*Mesmo que mude o subscribe/post para subscribe/post-json, nada muda.

Quem puder me ajudar, agradeço.
Não estou conseguindo localizar o problema.

Comment: Você sabe o que é CORS?

Comment: eu ate entendo um pouco, mas nada tão profundo. Até cheguei a colocar no htaccess e no php ( Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * ), mas nada.